# ASP.NET Grid View Problem

Tags: asp.net

I have one gridview where I am passing the command argument as gridview row id for the Button I created for every row.

I want to display all the details of that row in the textbox according to the Row clicked.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCategory" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
              onrowcommand="gvCategory_RowCommand" >
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblCatId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("categoryId") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblCatName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("categoryName") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnModify" runat="server" Text="Modify" CommandName="Modify" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("categoryId") %>' />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
```

Code.....

```
if (e.CommandName == "Modify")
{
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);          
     // I want the value to assgin for the selected row here
     // I was previously fetching the data from database according id,but i want this frim the gridview of selected row.
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that e.CommandArgument is the expected categoryID?

Comment: I would suggest changing your question title to reflect the actual problem too.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? If my answer helped you, please mark it so that others users can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a quick example of how to do what you're trying to do. It works for me.

### The Example Solution

Default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="StudentsDS"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    OnRowCommand="myGridView_RowCommand"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="myGridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="FullName" 
            SortExpression="FullName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ClassID" HeaderText="ClassID" 
            SortExpression="ClassID" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Modify" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStudent" runat="server" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="StudentsDS" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Sandbox %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Student"
/>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void myGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "Select") {
        // do something here if you want, although not necessary
    }
}

protected void myGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // show "FullName" field of selected row in textbox
    txtStudent.Text = myGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

### How It Works

Upon clicking "Modify" in a row, the textbox updates to show the FullName field of the selected row.

The important part is that instead of a `TemplateField`, use a `CommandField` with `ShowSelectButton="True"`. Then do what you need to do in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Note that the `SelectText` of the `CommandField` is set to "Modify" as you desired. You can also set the `ButtonType` property of the `CommandField` to be button, image, or link.

### Making It Better

I would also advise that instead of using a `SqlDataSource` as I have, you use an `ObjectDataSource` so that you can do something like

```
protected void myGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MyModelObject o = myGridView.SelectedRow.DataItem as MyModelObject;
    txtStudent.Text = o.MyProperty;
}
```

You may also consider wrapping your GridView in an UpdatePanel to prevent full postbacks / page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

After you have the lineID, you select that line, and then you have the CategoryID on selected value

```
int iTheIndexNow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);    

// select that line to see it visual as selected, and get the value on next line
gvCategory.SelectedIndex = iTheIndexNow;    

// here is your categoryID that   
//you can use to open your database with and get the text
gvCategory.SelectedValue // == categoryID
```

On GridView you must have set your KeyID

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="categoryId" .... >
```

Comment: I want the value to display in the text box which i selected in the grid view.

Comment: @user373083 I do not see the textbox, where is it ? , anyway just type txtBox.Text = gvCategory.SelectedValue;

Comment: protected void gvCategory_RowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.CommandName == "Modify")
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);          
            txtCategory.Text = gvCategory.Rows[id].Cells[2].Text.ToString();

        }
    }

Comment: @bitxwise Yes its read only, is the CategoryID that can use to read the database selected line and use it.

Comment: My comment was incomplete, but it doesn't matter anymore =) Sorry for the confusion!